# Is it a coincidence that the acronym SNSD is the same in Korean and Chinese?

Tags: names, asian, language, korean, k-pop

SNSD is a Korean pop group otherwise known as [Girls' Generation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Girls%27_Generation) outside of Asian.

In Korean, it is "So Nyeo Shi Dae", to be honest I can almost pronounce it the same in Chinese. In Chinese it is 少女時代 and the pinyin for it is "Shao Nu Shi Dai" which also turns into SNSD.

As far as I know these 2 languages don't share anything common. Is it just a coincidence that the acronym SNSD is the same in both languages?

Comment: Also in Japan they are known as 少女時代（しょうじょじだい/shoujyojidai). If you try to do the letter thing you get SJJD which is different. Ultimately, this is a question about Eastern language romanization, not about music itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Korean does have a lot of Chinese-based vocabulary, and two of the Chinese-based words are

- **少女 / Korean "소녀"** ("So Nyeo") - in English, literally "young female"
  or "girl"
- **時代 / Korean "시대"** ("Shi Dae") - in English, literally "time
  generation" or "generation"

So no, it's not a coincidence : they are the same words.

Incidentally, you know 現代 cars, right? That's Hyundai or 현대 - literally "current generation". So the "Dae" in *So Nyeo Shi Dae* is the same as the "dai" in Hyundai - they're just different romanisations.

Comment: Interesting, I don't know about the Hyundai thing, I don't even know what that is in Chinese.